# accessing entire resultset in sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I want to get all the results of a solr search.

Consider this example:

```
@search = Post.search do
  with(:blog_id, 1)
  fulltext("pizza")
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 50
end

@posts = @search.results
@rows_num = @search.total
```

The total number of rows returned is 250. By default, 50 rows are displayed on each page.

So far, everything is fine.

I now need to get all the search results (the 250 results) to do some further processing. 
`@posts` only contains the 50 rows displayed on the page.

`@posts.all` doesn't seem to work.

How do I access the entire resultset of a sunspot solr search?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know either Ruby or Sunspot, on your query there is the :per_page parameter with 50 as value on it. On solr HTTP REST API this should be the equivalent as the rows=x param, according to the sunspot API docs. Basically this is the parameter that tells how many results to return on a single query. If it's value would be 1000000, it would always return all results in the query, up to a million, regardless of how many were found.

Make a second query with a higher limit to get all the docs. Choose an upper limit you can deal with, as some queries can match and return the entire index, given sufficiently high value for rows.